# reserve array memory in advance in Julia

Tags: julia

How can we reserve memory (or allocate memory without initialization) in Julia? In C++, a common pattern is to call `reserve` before calling `push_back` several times to avoid having to call on `malloc` more than once. Is there an equivalent in Julia?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I think you are looking for `sizehint!`

```
help?> sizehint!
search: sizehint!

  sizehint!(s, n)

  Suggest that collection s reserve capacity for at least n elements. This can
  improve performance.
```